# BigQuery - Aggregate by 2 months window

Tags: google-bigquery

So currently im currently doing a project on BQ to obtain monthly level data using the codes below.

```
WITH agg as (
  SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(CAST(date as DATE), MONTH) AS year_month,
  market,
  SUM(Rev) as Rev,
FROM `data_table` 
group by 1,2)
```

However now i am required to get it at a 2 month level. Expected results would be like this.

| Date | Market | Rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2021 | JP | (sum of Jan & Feb Rev) |
| Mar 2021 | JP | (sum of Mar & Apr Rev) |
| May 2021 | JP | (sum of May & Jun Rev) |
| Jan 2021 | MY | (sum of Jan & Feb Rev) |
| Mar 2021 | MY | (sum of Mar & Apr Rev) |
| May 2021 | MY | (sum of May & Jun Rev) |

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%b %Y', 
    DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(date AS DATE)), 2 * DIV(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(date AS DATE)) - 1, 2) + 1, 1)
  ) AS Date,
  Market,
  SUM(Rev) AS Rev,
FROM `data_table` 
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

with output like below

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! Clean and straightforward

Comment: How could I change the formula if I wanted a 3 month window instead of 2?

Comment: simply change `2` to `3` in second line of the code - there are two such entries to change :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast all februarys to januars, aprils to march etc.

Along the lines of

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH dummy_data as (
    SELECT "JAN" as month, 1 as revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT "FEB" as month, 1 as revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT "MAR" as month, 1 as revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT "APR" as month, 1 as revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT "MAY" as month, 1 as revenue
), cast_months as (
    SELECT 
        CASE month
            WHEN "FEB" then "JAN"
            WHEN "APR" then "MAR"
            WHEN "JUN" then "MAY"
            ELSE month
        END as month,
        revenue,
    FROM test
)
SELECT 
    month,
    SUM(revenue) as total_revenue,
FROM casted 
GROUP BY month
```

Seems to be the most straightforward way to do it.